# Linq to SQL optional column, sql generated field

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a property in my Linq to SQL class that doesn't actually exist in my database.

I only populate this column during one query (namely for ranked searching)

```
            IEnumerable<BookingType> results = db.ExecuteQuery<BookingType>
            (
            "(SELECT  mm.rcount AS SearchRank, 
            b.* FROM (SELECT m.TourID AS myId, COUNT(m.RecordType) AS rcount 
            FROM (((SELECT * FROM Bookings h WHERE h.RecordType = 'H' 
                    AND h.TourArea like '%bull%')
            union
            (SELECT * FROM Bookings t WHERE t.RecordType = 'T' and t.TourGuideName like '%bull%')) ) m group by m.TourID) mm 
            INNER JOIN Bookings b ON mm.myId= b.TourID WHERE b.RecordType = 'H')", "bull"
            );
```

Heres part of the model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifier for a booking
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    [Column(DbType = "int", IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int? BookingID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Search Ranking
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    [Column(DbType = "int")]
    public int? SearchRank { get; set; }
```

When I run this against my ranked search query it works, very well indeed. When I run any other queries I get the error 'SearchRank field does not exist', because it doesn't exist. If I put the SearchRank field in the database then the field comes back null when doing ranked search (presumably because the b.* portion of my query returns SearchRank too.

**Is there a way to set some sort of 'OptionalColumn' attribute on my model?**

Other wise I'll have to put the SearchRank column in the DB and then write out each individual column names for the RankedSearch query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure if this will work)

Add virtual to your SearchRank property, and remove the column attribute from BookingType

```
e.g. public virtual int? SearchRank { get; set; }
```

Create a new class "BookingType2" which inherits BookingType

In the new Class override the SearchRank property and add the Column attribute.

Change the signature of your execute method to BookingType2

```
e.g. db.ExecuteQuery<BookingType2>(...
```

If it works you should be able to cast the result back to BookingType.